# BERT Certainty (iOS)

Tags: ios, machine-learning, bert-language-model

I am currently integrating the BERT model listed on https://developer.apple.com/machine-learning/models/#text into an iOS application and have had difficulty removing answers that have low certainty.

I have used the sample code found at the link above but because I wanted to answer questions based on larger volumes of text, I loop over an array of paragraphs and predict an answer for each one. However, the model does not return nil or "No Answer" if an answer is not found and instead returns a (seemingly) random substring. I suppose what I am trying to ask is: is it possible to access the certainty of BERT's response to filter out unlikely results? Or is there another way to get BERT to only return results above a set certainty threshold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching, I've now found a solution. Ironically it only took three lines of code, but here it is anyway:

```
if bestSum < 7.5 {
    return nil
}
```

I implemented this in the `findBestLogitPair()` method in the `BERTOutput.swift` file as provided in Apple's sample code for text analysis using BERT. I have now discovered that the word logit does kind of mean probability in statistics - but being a programmer, I had no idea!